# How do I set up a rubber hand experiment with precise latency?

Tags: research

The rubber hand illusion ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multisensory_integration#Rubber_hand_illusion)) involves touching both a fake arm and a subject's real arm simultaneously. This causes the subject to feel that the fake arm belongs to him. Normally a human delivers both touches, so the timing is approximate. I want to vary the latency between the fake touch and real touch precisely (~5 ms at minimum) to probe how close they need to be to create the illusion. What can I use to touch a human and fake hand lightly at variable but precise times?

Comment: Easiest way here is a home-brew robot.
Use an arduino an 2 servo motors.

Comment: Does the system need to consider the difference in arm position (thickness) as part of this equation?  You may not need a very sophisticated system to simply execute one touch action 5ms behind another.  Do you have an automated way to test the timing differences before you start taking data?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a real-time system. Generally, you can do this either in a standalone or a hosted environment.

Standalone, otherwise known as bare-metal, means you write your code for a specific hardware, e.g. a microcontroller. That way, you have complete control of what executes and at what intervals, so you can be very precise. You can hardly go wrong with any microcontroller for such a simple task, so just choose one you like most.

Hosted environments means programming under a real-time operating system. There are a handful of those, but of course I would advocate free software. There are a couple of extensions for Linux that can make it real-time (RTAI, Xenomai, RT-Linux and others) and you can get precisions of even microseconds, which should be enough for your task.

Setting up a real-time Linux with proper configuration can be tricky, but once done the programming is easier and debugging tools are available. On the other hand, you can start programming a microcontroller right away and if you are experienced, not much more difficult than hosted either.

In the end it's your choice. If you feel comfortable with microcontrollers, I'd recommend a standalone application for your task.